# how to edit text in an image

Tags: software-recommendation

How can I edit text on a JPEG file that was emailed to me? I can figure out what program to use? It is currently saved with my pictures in my gallery, how can I move the file to a different program? I've tried and it will only let me save it to my gallery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can to edit the text in a JPEG image in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28850/how-can-to-edit-the-text-in-a-jpeg-image-in-photoshop)

Answer (score 2):

You can not edit the text in JPEG file, you can do one thing open that file to Photoshop and erase the text using Tools-->Clone stamp then re-type and save.